# Using an Image As an Opacity Mask

Tags: image-processing

The following link shows using an Image As an Opacity Mask.

https://wpf.2000things.com/2012/05/14/557-using-an-image-as-an-opacity-mask/

But I am not able to get intended result...

Are you able to get intended result?

I think we should make one of that images is **transparent**.

If so please tell me how can I do that.

If you are able to get intended result then please put your images to **OneDrive** in order to I can download.

By the way it looks easy job but it is not easy.

By the way I have used **paint.net** for designing transparent images.

Comment: What have you done so far ?

Comment: When I ask about what you've done so far, it's in terms of code. Their code works, yours don't, so post it.

Comment: I advise you to use Paint.net, make a new image, then draw your face, then with the magic wand, select the white background, then delete it. you will have a similary background (transparent), then save as png to manage the transparency.

Comment: Please refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question. The StackOverflow community is good at helping solve specific problems with code. Post what you've tried and explain why it's not working as intended. Help us to help you.

Comment: @JEllery In fact I think this is not the good place, as what he wants is to know how to draw it. In fact the question was not possible to understand, but understood with his comments.

Comment: You should upload your code and images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Anything through transparent regions in opacity mask will not be shown**

Here's a complete example:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image Source="rocks.png" Margin="10" />
        <Image Source="rocks.png" Margin="10">
            <Image.OpacityMask>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="mask1.png" />
            </Image.OpacityMask>
        </Image>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/opacity-masks-overview#using-an-image-as-an-opacity-mask

I have put everything you need to understand how it works, open the opacity mask in something like Paint.NET and you should understand how to replicate that.

Comment: The one on the left is just to show the original image.

Comment: Glad it helped you out!

Comment: By the way I have got 4 downvotes. In order to reset my downvotes please delete your answer. When you delete your answer I will delete the whole post.

Comment: There's a really good reason on why you can't delete your question: people have invested time in it

Comment: When I started asking questions in this web site I got the same exact result as you, just get over it, it's not the end of the world!